# Reloading a button on event change in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having a simple form in React, which looks like:

```
const [placeOptions] = useState([
     { value: 'USA', label: 'USA' },
     { value: 'MEX', label: 'Mexico' },
]);
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [place, setPlace] = useState('USA');
....

<input onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)} type="text"/>
<select onChange={event => setPlace(event.target.value)}>
    {placeOptions.map(item => (
        <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
            {item.label}
        </option>
    ))}
</select>

<CustomButton id="custom-btn" props={[name, place]} />
```

The above Custom button is just rendering once and is taking the default null and 'USA' value. It should Ideally send props to every event change, possibly refreshing the component once event is triggered. I am unable to determine how do I refresh a component on event change and pass the correct state to the props.

Edit: The below is the CustomButton.tsx file:

```
export function CustomButton({ props, id }: { props?:any, id?:string}) {
    var name = props ? props[0] : '';
    var place = props ? props[1] : '';
    
    useEffect(() => {
        renderButton(id);
    }
    
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id={id}></div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );

    async function renderButton(id: string) {
        ... // Some logic involving the props passed
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
This the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-dust-315dk?file=/src/App.js

All I want is to change the props too and dynamically render the custom button.

Comment: Firstly the way you are passing props is unique and I have personally not seen it anywhere. Also I hope all your tags are inside the return statement. Please add that part of your code.

Comment: Is CustomButton a pure component / using React.memo?

Comment: Well, what is the suggested way to pass the props? Yes, the CustomButton is a pure function based React component.

Comment: So a pure function and a react **Pure** component is a little different. Also you can pass props as individual values. But pls update your question with Custom Button definition so people coming in later do not have to go through comments

Comment: Okay cool will update. Thanks

Comment: This should work ideally. Maybe you can create a minimal reproducable example on codeSandbox.

Comment: Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-dust-315dk?file=/src/App.js
It is not almost same, but works as a replicate

Comment: Your sandbox code is working. Have a look and update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you define the name and the place variable in CustomButton Component.
Variables of javascript defined like `var` `let`, and `const` will not trigger re-renders in React Button. States and Props only can trigger re-renders in React Components.
So if you do something like this in the parent file:

```
// All same code excepet
<CutomButtom id="cutom-btn" name={name} place={place} />
```

You can get name and place directly from props and use them as it is like:

```
export function CustomButton({ name, place, id }: { name: string, place: string, id:string}){
// NO need for defining name and place now, just use them directly...  
}
```

Another improvement you can make is to define  PropsType separately:

```
export interface CustomButtonProps  {
id: string;
name:string;
place:string;
}


export function CustomButton({name, place, id}:CustomButtonProps){

}
```